# How do I check if each of the characters in my string, is just one specific letter?

Tags: c#, string

How do I check if my whole string is nothing but one letter for each of the character positions? For example, I want to check that the string variable "Word1" only contains "_" (underscores).

Lets say Word1 = "____"; How can the program check to make sure there are no letters just underscores in that variable?

Answer (score 5):

Use Linq [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
char charToTest = '_';
var result = myString.All(x => x == charToTest);
```

Returns `true` only if the `charToTest` was found on any position. Furthermore when any position has another character the statement immedialtly returns `false` without checking for further positions.

EDIT: As @CSharpie pointed out this will also return `true` if your string is empty. To avoid this check for `String.IsNullOrEmpty` before:

```
var result = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) && myString.All(x => x == charToTest);
```

Comment: Note that it also returns true when myString is empty. So your first sentence isnt entirely correct.

Comment: @CSharpie Yeap, thanks for the hint, I´ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Linq (`using System.Linq`)

```
if (Word1.All(c => c == '_'))
{
    // only underscores
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Linq All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) is the cleanest way but you can also use regex for this task.
Something like: `^(_+)$` will match only if there is one or more `_`

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(_+)$");
    if (match.IsMatch(myString))
        Console.WriteLine("Matched");
```

Comment: You can clean this up alot by using the static [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You dont need to instantiate when using the static version. e.g. Regex.IsMatch(myString,@"^(_+)$")

Comment: Furthermore you also don´t need a matching group, you can omit the paranthesis.

Comment: II think that parenthesis make the regex more cleaner but I perfectly know that in this situation the parenthesis are useless